# Functional property name?

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, universal-property

I would like to know if this functional property has a name.

**Definition.** We say that a functional $L$ has a *property* if and only if $L(f) \leq L(g)$ implies
$$
L(f) \leq L\left(\frac{f+g}{2}\right) \leq L(g).
$$

Do you know if this property has a name?

Comment: If $L$ maps $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ (and if $L$) is continuous, this should be equivalent to monotonicity (decreasing or increasing).

Comment: Yes, but I am specially interested in functionals that represent non-linear integrals. Currently, I am interested in decomposition integrals and there is easy to find functions $f,g$ such that $L(f) \leq L(g)$ but the inequality $L(f) \leq L((f+g)/2) \leq L(g)$ does not hold. As other example, the integrals that are linear have the mentioned property.

Comment: Your functional is quasiconvex and quasiconcave. Sometimes this is called 'quasilinear'.

Comment: Can you provide some references? Thanks

Comment: At least it's on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function